# Query to find out the second Saturday of each month of the year

Tags: mysql

I need help to write one query:

How do I find out the second Saturday of each month of the year?

Comment: are you need this in a single query?

Answer (score 1):

There is a good technique demonstrating how to do this [here](http://oreilly.com/catalog/sqlhks/chapter/ch04.pdf). Scroll down to Tip #23. It will have you create a small table to facilitate the query. Once you have the table created, your query is something like this:

```
SELECT monthdate AS first_day_of_month,
    DATE_ADD(monthdate, 
        INTERVAL( ( 10 - DAYOFWEEK(monthdate) ) % 7 ) + 7 DAY) AS second_saturday_of_month
FROM monthdates
```

Comment: Hello orbman, i just go through your pdf and i workout the logic for this.  Your answer has little modification. Just see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is workout from orbman idea, thanks orbman.

First your table is like this,

```
CREATE TABLE `monthdates` (
  `monthdate` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`monthdate`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;

INSERT INTO `monthdates` VALUES ('2010-02-01');
INSERT INTO `monthdates` VALUES ('2010-03-01');
INSERT INTO `monthdates` VALUES ('2010-04-01');
INSERT INTO `monthdates` VALUES ('2010-05-01');
INSERT INTO `monthdates` VALUES ('2010-06-01');
INSERT INTO `monthdates` VALUES ('2010-07-01');
```

In this table, your providing the first date of month.

Then use this query for second saturday,

```
    SELECT monthdate AS first_day_of_month, DATE_ADD(monthdate, INTERVAL( ( 14 - DAYOFWEEK(monthdate) ) % 7 ) + 7 DAY) AS second_saturday_of_month, DAYNAME(DATE_ADD(monthdate, INTERVAL( ( 14 - DAYOFWEEK(monthdate) ) % 7 ) + 7 DAY)) as dayy
 FROM monthdates
```

Output Is :

```
first_day_of_month  second_saturday_of_month    dayy
2010-02-01  2010-02-13  Saturday
2010-03-01  2010-03-13  Saturday
2010-04-01  2010-04-10  Saturday
2010-05-01  2010-05-08  Saturday
2010-06-01  2010-06-12  Saturday
2010-07-01  2010-07-10  Saturday
```

Comment: Hi Karthik,

Thanks for the help,
If i have any issue i will get back to you..
Thanks a lot once again...

Riddhi

Comment: Hi Karthik can you please explain that what % in this Query i mean what is the % do in that

Comment: % is modulo operator dear.  It gives the remainder value.

Comment: oho..this i know from my schooling days dear...but i want logic

Comment: Hi riddhi, are you need in solution or logic?
Ok logic part DATE_ADD(monthdate, INTERVAL( ( 14 - DAYOFWEEK(monthdate) ) % 7 ) + 7 DAY).
It is big part that i workout from orbman pdf.
See this link http://oreilly.com/catalog/sqlhks/chapter/ch04.pdf
Refer Tip #23 section.